# WP List Table in custom post type

Tags: api, wp-list-table

I want to use WP_List_Table class on a custom post type to create a whole new admin panel (the original one will exist, but I want to have several others with specific filters and criteria set upon them).

I've tried the [smashing tutorial](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/03/native-admin-tables-wordpress/), but I don't know how to apply them into the existing post/page object (they use it for pure database tables outside wordpress standard tables for post/pages/custom types).

Comment: Why create whole new admin pages? Why not alter the filters on the main page?

Comment: Because the admin user would have full access to that page (native page), but the admin panel that I am preparing is destined for customers that need to do things mechanical on the pages (simple replacements mostly and occasionally add a custom post type I call slide for a slideshow, but I don't want him to change options like taxonomy or specific custom fields).